# Visual Studio 2015 Installer doesn't install cl.exe

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I had installed Visual Studio 2017 on my machine with VC2015.3 C++ compiler toolset. The VC14 compiler is now located in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe`

Now, when I install Visual Studio 2015 and select to install "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" there is no `cl.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` as expected and as it always have been.

It's just like the installer "know" that I have already VC14 compiler installed (through VS2017) and skips it completely.

What is the issue here?