# Parallel Installation of VS2017 and VS2015 breaks cmake (and more)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 15.4.0, then i installed VS2015 Update 3 (
C++ Language only).

I started VS2015 and tried to create a C++ Project (e.g. Console Application) but nothing happens, the dialog just does not close or continue. Only "Cancel" is possible. More important for me, i tried to configure a project (caffe2) as a VS2015 project, but cmake failes to find the VS2015 tool set.

The problem (or a part of the problem) is, that VS2015 normally installs its toolset (cl.exe etc.) to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

But because of VS2017, it uses now:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin
```

(see also [Visual Studio 2015 Installer doesn't install cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270812/visual-studio-2015-installer-doesnt-install-cl-exe/47051388#47051388))

CMake (3.9.4) does not find the rc.exe or cl.exe of VS2015 anymore

I tried uninstalling both studios and reinstall them starting with VS2015, but VS2015 is still using the shared folder and not its own. (Even worth, i now got a mix of both folders, some minor important files are now duplicated). As a workaround, i started cmd.exe in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC",renamed bin,lib,include,redist to bin#,lib#,... and used hardlinks like this

```
mklink /j bin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin"
mklink /j lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\lib"
mklink /j redist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\redist"
mklink /j include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\include"
```

At least, cmake is now working again, but i still cannot create any projects with VS2015 anymore ( i do not need this VS2015 functionality really, but it makes a bad feeling having a broken installation)

Is anyone else having this trouble and got a better solution than the workaround above ?

Comment: Why would you use VS 2015 when you have VS2017?

Comment: VS 2017 does not work well with CUDA 8 (at least, cmake does not produce correct vcxproj's) and CUDA 9 support for VS2017 is still marked as beta. Caffe2 (a deep learning network library) uses CUDA. That way i am forced to use VS2015 for all CUDA projects...

Comment: At least for the CMake part see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917454/cmake-how-to-specify-the-version-of-visual-c-to-work-with). Running CMake out of the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" should work (without the need to use hardlinks for the regular installation paths). And you could try to use VS2017 with `-T "v140"` toolset for VS2015 compatibility.

Comment: Typically the issues with upgrading from VS 2015 to VS 2017 may arise from improved standard support in newer compiler and from unknown (to code) compiler version numbers. If cmake does not produce correct project files for VS 2017 it may be a good idea to create a question describing this problem.

Comment: @VTT: Your comments are kind of off-topic regarding the question and only add clutter. I know, my comment does the same.

Comment: I don't think @VTT is off-topic at all. Removing VS2015 is a pretty viable solution. Timm even states he doesn't need VS2015.

Comment: I don't think @VTT is off-topic , too. But i still need VS2015 at least until there is a solution for cmake/cuda. I am not sure, that it is a cmake or a cuda problem. In fact, i have just no idea. I will try to wait for CUDA 9.x and CMake 10.x hoping that after some time, VS2017,CMake and Cuda live in harmony. But until that, i have to use VS2015, i think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe)